# Two dimensional array on iCarousel not showing images

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array, icarousel

Hi please help I am a newbie. I just created a two dimensional array and feed it to Nick Lockwood iCarousel. The Idea is that when I try to change the image lets say from image from array index 1 to image array index 2, certain data will shows up. My problem is that the images does not shows up in the carousel view that i have made.  Here is the source code. I have searched the wed to my very best but failed to find solution.

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(__unused iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view{
if (view == nil) {
    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 260.0f, 260.0f)];
    view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
}

for (NSArray* aSelection in self.itemCarousel) {
    NSLog(@"Data: %@", aSelection);

    UIImage *accmtImge = [aSelection objectAtIndex:2];
    UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:accmtImge];
    myImageView.frame = view.frame;

    CALayer *imageLayer = myImageView.layer;
    [imageLayer setCornerRadius:5];
    [imageLayer setBorderWidth:1.8f];
    [imageLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.525 green:0.376 blue:0.557 alpha:1] CGColor]];
    [imageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [myImageView.layer setCornerRadius:myImageView.frame.size.width/2];
    [view addSubview:myImageView];
}
return view;}
```

Comment: this is the sample array in the self.itemCarousel: Data: (
    dummy,
    data,
    "<UIImage: 0x7fc36954a860>, {260, 260}",
    dummy,
    data
)

Comment: it is possible to load a two dimensional on Nick Lockwood  iCarousel?